# what is the difference between serializationUtils.clone(obj) and obj.clone() method

Tags: java

what is the difference between serializationUtils.clone(obj) and obj.clone() method

As far I know that both are used for cloning.one is from obj class and other from apache.commons.lang package.

When should we use these methods?

Comment: have you looked at the [javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html#clone-T-)?? "This is many times slower than writing clone methods by hand on all objects in your object graph. However, for complex object graphs, or for those that don't support deep cloning this can be a simple alternative implementation. Of course all the objects must be Serializable."

Answer (score 1):

**SerializationUtils**

Assists with the serialization process and performs additional functionality based on serialization.

```
    Deep clone using serialization
    Serialize managing finally and IOException
    Deserialize managing finally and IOException
```

Deep clone an Object using serialization.

This is many times slower than writing clone methods by hand on all objects in your object graph. However, for complex object graphs, or for those that don't support deep cloning this can be a simple alternative implementation. Of course all the objects must be Serializable.

**Clone Method**

The clone() method saves the extra processing task for creating the exact copy of an object. If we perform it by using the new keyword, it will take a lot of processing time to be performed that is why we use object cloning.